# Deleting functions in running scripts? Tkinter Python 3.5

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter, python, I'm trying to make a program so when `Up` is clicked, 1 is added to a number (using StringVar to show it), and when the number gets to 10, it is restarted to 0. I've managed to complete this part, but I want to enable it so after a certain amount of time, the number can no longer be changed. For example, I hold down the `Up` button for a certain given amount of time, and the last number I get is a 6. Now, I want it to stay on 6, no matter how many times I press `Up`. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
hwd1 = 0
mult = 1
hwd = StringVar()
hwd.set("0")
def add1(event):
    global hwd
    global hwd1
    on = True
    if on:
        hwd1 += 1*(mult)
        hwd.set(str(hwd1));
    if hwd1 == 10:
        hwd1 = 0
        hwd.set("0")

label = Label(root, textvariable=hwd)
label.pack()





root.bind_all('<Up>', add1)
```

This code shows the first part of what I have done, but when I try to do the second part, here's what I done:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
hwd1 = 0
mult = 1
hwd = StringVar()
hwd.set("0")

def deladd():
    global add1
    del(add1)

def add1(event):
    global add1
    global hwd
    global hwd1
    on = True
    if on:
        hwd1 += 1*(mult)
        hwd.set(str(hwd1));
    if hwd1 == 10:
        hwd1 = 0
        hwd.set("0")
    root.after(5000, deladd)

label = Label(root, textvariable=hwd)
label.pack()




root.bind_all('<Up>', add1)
```

From using this code, I get an error message saying `add1 referenced before assignment` and I'm not sure why. I'd appreciate some help, so thanks for your time :)

-Jake

Comment: Why are you declaring `global add1` under the callback `add1`?

Comment: That must have been a mistake, sorry :/

Comment: It seems you are trying to delete a function named `add1`. Is that correct? Or is `add1` supposed to be a variable?

Comment: I am trying to make add1 delete after a certain period of time after a button is clicked.

Comment: - Found an answer to this question! Thanks for all the help guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a declaration - just edit your code and put `def add1` before `def deladd`

The problem is because `deladd()` is calling add1, but on the first call it can't 'reach' it.

Comment: This didn't change anything for me. I don't think this would work anyway because add1 is a function, not an integer.

Comment: My mistake - I used a bit of changing it around and I managed to make it work